# DataContractJsonSerializer retrieving information

Tags: c#

I'd like to get additional information from the `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

When I deserialize an object:

```
var deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(toType);
return deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

I don't get any errors if some useless properties have been added in the json.
I don't retrieve any usable information like missing property with the specific type we are talking about.
And some other things.

Do you guys know how I could retrieve those kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = "{'Id': 1, 'Salary': 100 }";

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Error = Error,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
        };

        var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json, settings);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Error(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs errorEventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(errorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
        errorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**End of update**

I think it can't do what you need. I would use Json.NET instead of DataContractJsonSerializer. It has such capabilities:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_MissingMemberHandling.htm

It throws an exception if your json has different properties that class.

You can easily install it via NuGet.

Comment: That seems more adapted, thank you, but I still need to parse the exception message to get my data.

Comment: @M.Christopher Please check my update, maybe it helps

Comment: Hi, yes that's this kind of thing I've implemented, you've helped me a lot! thank you

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would deserialize this way

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(sampleJson);
```

This gives you access to all of the data which you can query using

```
json.ContainsKey('foo');
```

To see if a property exist.

Or

```
json.GetEnumerator()
```

To allow you to loop through all of the elements.